# Category Coupon

Tags: commerce

I would like to setup a flexible system using the coupon module. I would like to add a term reference field to the coupon entity that refers to a product category/taxonomy.

Now my client can create a coupon and designate "10% off all Baby Shoes" where Baby Shoes is a taxonomy term set on each product display that contains baby shoe SKUs.

On coupon redemption, only products whose product displays are in the Baby Shoes category receive a discount.

Has anyone set something like this up before and would care to share the detail on how they did i

Comment: Sounds like a good idea for a new module. But I would rather add the tags to the product than to the product display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar module that allows you to add products directly to the coupon via an entity reference field : [Commerce Coupon by product reference](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_couponprodref).

Unfortunately Coupon module does not support this by default, however you can either wait for [the next version which is suppose to be much more flexible](http://drupal.org/node/1800954#comment-6549008), or follow the instructions in README.txt to [install this sandbox module](http://drupal.org/sandbox/agileadam/1798958), which is like coupon by product reference, but uses terms.